# How do I render endless terrain using TerrainGrid?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I have started to learn game development, using the jMonkey engine. I am able to create single tile of terrain using `TerrainQuad`, but in the next step, I'm stuck at making it infinite. I have gone through the wiki and a [tutorial](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_terrain), and want to use the `TerrainGrid` class, but my code does not seem to work. I have looked around on the web, and searched other forums, but cannot find any other code example to help.

I believe in the below code; `ImageTileLoader` returns an image, which is the height map for that tile. I have modified it to return the same image, every time, but all I see is a black window. The `Namer` method is not even called.

```
terrain = new TerrainGrid("terrain", patchSize, 513, 
    new ImageTileLoader(assetManager, new Namer() {
        public String getName(int x, int y) {
            //return "Scenes/TerrainMountains/terrain_" + x + "_" + y + ".png";
            System.out.println("X = " + x + ", Y = " + y);
            return "Textures/heightmap.png";
        }
    }));
```

---

This is the result, when I use `TerrainQuad`:

[image: My result with terrain quad]

---

This is my full code:

```
// Sample 10 - How to create fast-rendering terrains from heightmaps, and how to
// use texture splatting to make the terrain look good.
public class HelloTerrain extends SimpleApplication {
    private TerrainQuad terrain;
    Material mat_terrain;
    private float grassScale = 64;
    private float dirtScale = 32;
    private float rockScale = 64;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloTerrain app = new HelloTerrain();
        app.start();
    }

    private FractalSum base;
    private PerturbFilter perturb;
    private OptimizedErode therm;
    private SmoothFilter smooth;
    private IterativeFilter iterate;

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        flyCam.setMoveSpeed(200);

        initMaterial();

        AbstractHeightMap heightmap = null;
        Texture heightMapImage = assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/heightmap.png");
        heightmap = new ImageBasedHeightMap(heightMapImage.getImage());
        heightmap.load();

        int patchSize = 65;

        terrain = new TerrainGrid("terrain", patchSize, 513, 
            new ImageTileLoader(assetManager, new Namer() {
            public String getName(int x, int y) {
                System.out.println("X = " + x + ", Y = " + y);
                return "Textures/heightmap.png";
                // set to return the same height map image.
            }
        }));

        terrain.setMaterial(mat_terrain);
        terrain.setLocalTranslation(0,-100, 0);
        terrain.setLocalScale(2f, 1f, 2f);
        rootNode.attachChild(terrain);

        TerrainLodControl control = new TerrainLodControl(terrain, getCamera());
        terrain.addControl(control);
    }

    public void initMaterial() {
        // TERRAIN TEXTURE material
        this.mat_terrain = new Material(this.assetManager, 
            "Common/MatDefs/Terrain/HeightBasedTerrain.j3md");

        // GRASS texture
        Texture grass = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/white.png");
        grass.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("region1ColorMap", grass);
        this.mat_terrain.setVector3("region1", new Vector3f(-10, 0, this.grassScale));

        // DIRT texture
        Texture dirt = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/white.png");
        dirt.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("region2ColorMap", dirt);
        this.mat_terrain.setVector3("region2", new Vector3f(0, 900, this.dirtScale));

        Texture building = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/building.png");
        building.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);

        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("slopeColorMap", building);
        this.mat_terrain.setFloat("slopeTileFactor", 32);
        this.mat_terrain.setFloat("terrainSize", 513);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the GameDev StackExchange. We hope that you enjoy your time here on this site. If you haven't already, we recommend that you read the [site guide](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help). Keep in mind that the more research you put into your questions, the better results you will get. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I worked further on my problem and was able to achieve what I wanted to. But I still cannot understand what was the error on my first code. Below is the final code that I got by modifying the `TerrainGrid` example from [here](https://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/browse/trunk/engine/src/test/jme3test/terrain/TerrainGridTest.java). Below is the final code for anyone who falls into the same situation. It is not the final thing but does answer my question above.

```
public class TerrainGridTest extends SimpleApplication {

    private Material mat_terrain;
    private TerrainGrid terrain;
    private float grassScale = 64;
    private float dirtScale = 16;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        TerrainGridTest app = new TerrainGridTest();
        app.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        this.flyCam.setMoveSpeed(100f);
        initMaterial();
        initTerrain();
        this.getCamera().setLocation(new Vector3f(0, 200, 0));
        this.getCamera().lookAt(new Vector3f(0,0,0), Vector3f.UNIT_Y);
        this.viewPort.setBackgroundColor(new ColorRGBA(0.7f, 0.8f, 1f, 1f));
        initLight();
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(final float tpf) {

    }

    public void initMaterial() {
        // TERRAIN TEXTURE material
        this.mat_terrain = new Material(this.assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Terrain/HeightBasedTerrain.j3md");


        // GRASS texture
        Texture grass = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/white.png");
        grass.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("region1ColorMap", grass);
        this.mat_terrain.setVector3("region1", new Vector3f(-10, 0, this.grassScale));

        // DIRT texture
        Texture dirt = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/white.png");
        dirt.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("region2ColorMap", dirt);
        this.mat_terrain.setVector3("region2", new Vector3f(0, 900, this.dirtScale));

        // ROCK texture
        //Texture rock = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/Rock2/rock.jpg");
        Texture building = this.assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/building.png");
        building.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);


        this.mat_terrain.setTexture("slopeColorMap", building);
        this.mat_terrain.setFloat("slopeTileFactor", 32);

        this.mat_terrain.setFloat("terrainSize", 513);
    }

    private void initLight() {
        DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight();
        light.setDirection((new Vector3f(-0.5f, -1f, -0.5f)).normalize());
        rootNode.addLight(light);
    }

    private void initTerrain() {
        this.terrain = new TerrainGrid("terrain", 65, 257, new ImageTileLoader(assetManager, new Namer() {

            public String getName(int x, int y) {
               //return "Interface/Scenes/TerrainMountains/terrain_" + x + "_" + y + ".png";
                return "Textures/heightmap.png";
            }
        }));

        this.terrain.setMaterial(mat_terrain);
        this.terrain.setLocalTranslation(0, 0, 0);
        this.terrain.setLocalScale(3f, 1.5f, 3f);
        this.rootNode.attachChild(this.terrain);

        TerrainLodControl control = new TerrainGridLodControl(this.terrain, getCamera());
        control.setLodCalculator( new DistanceLodCalculator(65, 2.7f) ); // patch size, and a multiplier
        this.terrain.addControl(control);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting problem. Thanks for sharing the details. I also started game dev with jme3, you can test my game here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dangerworld/

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and i managed to solve it. 
You have to use TerrainGridLodControl to make it work, as TerrainLodControl doesn't work.
Looks like we failed to notice that when changing from TerrainQuad to TerrainGrid.